# EasyAuthModule_32 bit Error 401 in xamarin forms aad authentication

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services, azure-active-directory

please kindly help me out with my attempt to implement client side authentication for a xamarin forms aplication i am developing. i have followed every single tutorial on how to integrate Azure active directory into xamarin when using azure mobile services. the error is always thrown at the point of calling loginAsync. on futher investigation using the azure log i found out that the error was coming from the easyauthmodule. please help like i said i have followed every single tutorial on this issue and i have been on it now everyday for the past one week

please find my code below

```
try

       {
                AuthenticationContext ac = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
                ac.TokenCache.Clear();
                AuthenticationResult ar = await ac.AcquireTokenAsync(resource,    clientId, new Uri(returnUri), new PlatformParameters(this));
                JObject payload = new JObject();
                payload["access_token"] = ar.AccessToken;
               // DataRepository.DefaultManager.CurrentClient.Logout();
                user = await DataRepository.DefaultManager.CurrentClient.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.WindowsAzureActiveDirectory,payload);


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                CreateAndShowDialog(ex.Message, "Authentication failed");
            }
```

Comment: NOTIFY_MODULE_START ModuleName="EasyAuthModule_32bit", Notification="AUTHENTICATE_REQUEST", fIsPostNotification="false" 17:35:29.541
67. MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS

Warning ModuleName="EasyAuthModule_32bit", Notification="AUTHENTICATE_REQUEST", HttpStatus="401", HttpReason="Unauthorized", HttpSubStatus="71", ErrorCode="Unspecified error
 (0x80004005)", ConfigExceptionInfo="" 17:35:29.557
68. NOTIFY_MODULE_END ModuleName="EasyAuthModule_32bit", Notification="AUTHENTICATE_REQUEST", fIsPostNotificationEvent="false", NotificationStatus="NOTIFICATION_FINISH_REQUEST" 17:35:29.573

Answer (score 1):

EasyAuth is incompatible with Azure Mobile Services.  Are you sure you are using the right service moniker?

Make sure you are using the following NuGet for Azure Mobile Apps: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client/

EasyAuth is only available in Azure App Service.  You need to configure the App Service Authentication / Authorization module.  Assuming you have already integrated ADAL into your Xamarin app and have an access token from ADAL, your code is pretty close.  However, I've found that configuration of AAD for mobile apps is complex.  So I wrote a couple of blog posts about it.

Here is the server flow edition: https://shellmonger.com/2016/04/04/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-3-azure-ad-authentication/

Here is the client flow edition: https://shellmonger.com/2016/04/06/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-4-adal-integration/

Both are using Cordova as a mobile client, but the configuration of the service is identical.  The client details (aside from the obvious language differences) are similar as well.

Comment: i actually started the project as an azure mobile app service cos i followed [this] (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started/) to create the dotnet backend

Comment: i have followed the link for the client side implementation but still getting this error. what baffles me the most is that i do get a token back from AAD but mobile services refuse to recognize it, i also noticed that the tokens are always always expired, the expiryon is always set to the current time so at the time of debugging its already expired